# Two different types of user authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different Users for my app.  An Admin User and an Active User.  For my User actions, for example, I want anyone visiting the page to have access to actions [:new, :create].  But only an Admin User and an Active User to have access to actions [:edit, :update].  Now an Admin User's edit function is different from an Active User's edit function (e.g. the Admin User can set an Admin attribute for any user).  How do I differentiate between the two.  The only way I know is to have a before_filter for an :admin_user but then I also need a before_filter for an :active_user.  But these two conflict and I can't get into the actions with either user.

Comment: Take a gander at CanCan: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: om, I would like to roll this by hand as a Rails exercise.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer on Railscasts episodes #385 and #386.